# Is there a function to automatically calculate standard deviation from mean absolute error in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics, regression

I was wondering if there is some function to automatically calculate standard deviation from mean absolute error derived from sklearn.

here is an example dataset

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.datasets import make_regression

df = {
"a": [0.06 , 0.07, 0.45, 0.98, 0.97 ],
"b": [12,45,65, 56, 34],
"c": [2,5,5, 5, 3],
"d": [23,55,25, 15, 34],
"e": [0.0005,0.55555,0.383825, 0.4747477415, 0.348344334],
"f": [0.0236 , 0.3407, 0.4545, 0.9658, 0.4597 ],
"g": [70 , 90, 123, 154, 99 ],    
}

#load into df:
df = pd.DataFrame(df)

print(df)
```

and ml model

```
X = df.iloc[:, 0:6]
y = df.iloc[:, 6]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.5,random_state = 0)
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100, criterion='absolute_error', random_state=0)
```

then I use this all the way to calculate mean absolute error

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Preprocessing of validation data, get predictions
preds = model.predict(X_test)

# Evaluate the model
score = mean_absolute_error(y_test, preds)
print('The mean absolute error is:', score) 

# Preprocessing of test data, fit model
preds_val =model.predict(X_test)
```

As a result, score is helping me to get MAE. I tried to apply python function from statistics package to calculate the std and it does not worked. Could anyone suggest something from sklearn that can help to get the standard deviation of MAE?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by standard deviation of MAE? I guess you want to calculate the std of all errors? In that case subtract the model predictions from your observations and compute the std of that array.

Comment: Quick answer is no. You cannot calculate a standard deviation based only on the value of the mean absolute error.

Answer (score 0):

As far I know you can't compute the standard deviation (STD) from a Mean Absolute Error (MAE) but you can compute STD from the Absolute Error (AE):

```
>>> y_test.sub(preds).abs().std()
22.231790301278032

>>> y_test.sub(preds).abs().mean()  # same as mean_absolute_error(y_test, preds)
25.75
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for the **standard error** (standard deviation of the error relative to 0) you can use `mean_squared_error` :

```py
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

rmse = mean_squared_error(y_test, preds, squared=False)
31.5
```

RMSE is the Root Mean Squared Error, aka standard error.

Note: `squared=False` in `mean_squared_error` returns the RMSE instead of MSE (MSE=RMSE**2).